# Prove convergent sequence to the supremum

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

I asked to prove that a set of real numbers with a supremum not in the set contains a sequence converging to the supremum. I have most of the proof down, but I am not too sure where to bring in the fact that the least upper bound is not in the set.

Proof:

Let $X$ be a set of real numbers with a least upper bound $\alpha$. Suppose $\alpha\notin X$.

Now, because $\alpha$ is the supemum of $X$, for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists an element $x_{n}\in X$ such that $\alpha-\epsilon< x_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then, I want to say that because the least upper bound is not in the set, then for $N\in\mathbb{N}$, it follows that $x_n$.....Here is where I am not sure how to contine, but does this make sense to far?

Answer (score 0):

There exists some $x_{1}\in X$ such that $\alpha-1<x_{1}<\alpha$. There exists some $x_{2}\in X$ such that $\max\left\{\alpha-\dfrac{1}{2},x_{1}\right\}<x_{2}<\alpha$. Proceed in this way yields $\max\left\{\alpha-\dfrac{1}{n},x_{n-1}\right\}<x_{n}<\alpha$ with strictly increasing $(x_{n})$ of elements of $X$ and that $x_{n}\rightarrow\alpha$.

Comment: $x_{n}<\alpha$.

Comment: Actually whether or not the supremum is attained, such sequence always exists. Now the more interesting theorem is that, if it were not attainable, can you find a strictly increasing sequence for that? And this is what I proved. For attainable case, constant sequence will do.

Comment: If the supremum is in the set, then $x_{n}$ may be the supremum, so $x_{n}<\alpha$ then not holds. But your assumption that it is not in the set, so there is no way for $x_{n}=\alpha$, so $x_{n}<\alpha$ holds.

Comment: Not quite, you need to realize the $\epsilon$ to each $1/n$, if not, $\epsilon$ and $x_{n}$ that appear together make no sense.

Comment: What is your assertion of Archimedean property?

Comment: yes, this is what I am looking for.

Comment: oh there an n in the natural numbers such that 1/n < x for x in the real numbers for x positive

Comment: This is not needed in the proof.

Comment: With realizing each $\epsilon$ to $1/n$, you can find such $x_{n}$. And the fact that $x_{n}\rightarrow\alpha$ simply follows by Squeeze Theorem, why Archimedean is needed?

Comment: The fact that $\alpha-1/n<x_{n}\leq\alpha$, and the clear fact that $\alpha-1/n\rightarrow\alpha$, so that's it.

Comment: Okay, if you insist to use Archimedean, here's a little more: Given $\epsilon>0$, find some natural $N$ such that $n\geq 1/N$ then $1/n<\epsilon$, then $|\alpha-1/n-\alpha|=1/n<\epsilon$ for all such $n$, so that proves $\alpha-1/n\rightarrow\alpha$.

Comment: I mean do we have to give explicit numbers or can we make it more general

Comment: I don't follow. The $x_{2}$ must have in some sense closer to $\alpha$, $\alpha-1/2$ serves as a lower bound to squeeze $x_{2}$ closer to $\alpha$, and of course you can make it $\alpha-1/100$ to 'squeeze faster' either way you indeed need to specify, if not, how squeeze theorem applies?

Comment: You specify the lower bound $\alpha-1/n$ (or $\alpha-1/n^{2}$ whatever, as long as it goes to $\alpha$), then you apply the reasoning through Archimedean as what I have written in my comment, whether the supremum lies inside does not help the proof.

Comment: I see, I think I am just not sure how to connect with what I have left off in my proof to what I need to add.

Comment: You have just given you the answer! So it suggests that you may have stated the question in a sense of ill-posed. The supremum lies no inside is typically for the question like: is there strictly increasing sequence. For if no restriction applies to the sequence, then the assumption is just redundant.

Comment: Okay, then I do have the answer? But I thought you said I was not quite done earlier in the comments?

Comment: The only thing you need to rephrase is that $\epsilon$ to $1/n$ or any sort like that.

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach is to select for example $\epsilon_n = 2^{-n}$ so that $\lim \epsilon_n=0$. Your guarantee says that there are $x_n$ such that

$$\alpha - \epsilon_n < x_n < \alpha$$

Now both the RHS and LHS $\to\alpha$ as $n\to\infty$ so by the squeeze theorem $x_n\to\alpha$.

Note that you didn't need to assume that $\alpha\notin X$ as the squeeze theorem works even if you have non-strict inequalities.